# Opencart - Login with PayPal "authorization Code is invalid"

Tags: paypal, opencart

I'm trying to integrate the Login with `PayPal` module in my shop, but when I login it shows a blank page in:

```
http://www.myshop.com/index.php?route=m... 5YhZRcFVcj
```

In the error log I can see:

> ( [error] => invalid_authz_code [error_description] => Authorization
>   Code is invalid )
>
> 2015-10-09 9:44:51 - Log In with PayPal debug
>   (ModelModulePPLogin:getTokens) - cURL Response: stdClass Object (
>   [error] => invalid_authz_code [error_description] => Authorization
>   Code is invalid )

How do I address this?

Comment: Have you checked your PayPal API endpoint? Is it pointing to the LIVE environment or Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

"Login with PayPal" only returns the user_id unless updating the endpoint of the TokenService: `$endpoint = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice';`
that module currently has a switch for sandbox-mode, but only input fields for one of both credentials (which might be the source of confusion). see [Issue #3695](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/3695).